# Deny Default-Gateway changing rights to local Administrator

Tags: windows, networking, windows-xp

Is there any method to deny changing Default - Gateway ip-address to local Administrator?.

I have around 10 Helpdesk Engineer for better Troubleshooting on Client PC, i have included there domain username in Local Administrator.

Now sometime they change the Network IP address especially Default-Gateway of their PC, to bypass firewall.

Is there any log or any workaround through which i can track who has change the default gateway Ip address??

Comment: Similar questions have been asked here many times. You cannot prevent the administrator from overriding any settings they choose. That is the nature of the administrator account's privilege.

Comment: @jscott Thank you for your comment. Ok i agree with you, but is there any log, through which i can know who has change?

Comment: @param that is a completely separate question. If you really want the answer to that, you should ask it as its own question.

Comment: @MDMarra and Other - I apologize for the same...and Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give someone local administrator access to a computer, there's nothing that you can do to stop them from doing **anything**.

Comment: Of course you could extend that even farther.  If a person has physical access to a standard PC without any physical hardening, then they can do anything.  They don't even need access granted at the OS level.  A person smart enough to much around with changing the gateway, probably could manage to boot a livecd.